# What's the proper way of rounding NSDate on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I need to get the current date, but ignoring minutes and seconds, and then calculate an interval.

For example say that it's 7:30am right now, and I need to see how many hours it is until 5pm the next day, not counting the minutes, which means 7:30am should equal to 7am in this scenario, and the result should be 22 hours.

This could be easily done with

```
- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate
```

assuming that I'm able to create both ends of the interval.

The only option I thought of is using NSDateFormatter to output the current date into a string without the minutes, and then parse it back. But that doesn't seem like a very elegant and efficient solution.

**What I basically need to do is trim a NSDate to a specific precision, such as days, and trim the rest (7:50 to 7:00, etc.).**

Or is there any simple way I can do this the smarter way, where 7:50 gets roudned to 8:00 instead of 7:00?

I need to do this on iOS 5.

Comment: "doesn't seem like a very elegant and efficient solution".  It's two lines of code, and therefore very readable, (which seems pretty elegant to me). Will you be doing this operation thousands of times? Until you've seen that it actually needs optimization, why worry about it?  Of course this is just truncation, not rounding, as you say.

Comment: @Rayfleck - surely you jest? There is a huge difference between "premature optimization" and "we can write bad code". Darth is correct, doing this via formatting & parsing is inelegant and poor design; the lack of efficiency is only a secondary, but obvious, consideration. Programming is a mixture of art and science.

Comment: @CRD - part of the art of programming is knowing where good enough is.  That's why I asked if he's doing it thousands of times.  If so, then by all means search for an elegant solution.  If not, write the two lines of code, and move on with your life.  Readability and programmer time are just as important as clock-cycle time.  Sometimes there is no elegant solution, has anyone come up with one yet?
And I never said "premature optimization" -though I was thinking it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculations can be done with NSCalendar, instead of parsing you can use NSDateComponents.
When you take the hours and minutes from NSDateComponents, you can easily apply your rounding and convert the components back to a date.